# probability of an event calculated off its complement

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A hunter killed 10 animals, 2 of which are prohibited from being hunted. A wildlife inspector checks 2 random animals out of the total 10. What's the probability that the inspector will not check the 2 prohibited animals?

The answer is 
$$
\frac{\binom{8}{2}}{\binom{10}{2}} = \frac{28}{45}
$$

I wanted to solve the problem via calculating the probability of the event that the inspector did check the 2 prohibited animals (let this event be $A$). Then the event that the inspector doesn't check the 2 prohibited animals would be $A^C$, $A$'s complement. 
$$
A = \frac{\binom{2}{2}}{\binom{10}{2}} = \frac{1}{45}
$$
Then: 
$$
A^C = 1 -  \frac{1}{45} = \frac{44}{45}
$$

Which frankly I guess doesn't make sense but I don't understand why.

Comment: Actually, the probability you calculated is the probability that the inspector checked *both* prohibited animals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ways to inspect a prohibited animal would be
$${2\choose2}+{2\choose1}{8\choose1}$$
Because you could either choose both prohibited animals or one prohibited animal and one legal animal.

Comment: you're right! I didn't take into consideration the second scenario when the inspector checks just one animal.